# JVM_Read consuming CPU continuously

Tags: java, linux

I am new to java programming, found a process continuously consuming ~100% cpu.

[image]

And here is the pstack of the same thread.

```
Thread 99 (Thread 0x7f3ea8121700 (LWP 7133)):
#0  0x000000350920e82d in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f3eb5245431 in JVM_Read () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.191.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007f3eb46c1b57 in ?? () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.191.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
#3  0x00007f3ead08f4c6 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000006c5ebc440 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

What measures can be taken to stop consuming CPU?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`JVM_Read` implies that data is read from a file descriptor into a char array. This suggests that whatever is running on JVM is busy doing actual work.

It would be more practical to either take and inspect a thread dump (`kill -3 <PID>`) or read the program source code. There could be other factors involved e.g. background GC threads.